# How to convert []int8 to string

Tags: string, go, type-conversion, slice

What's the best way (fastest performance) to convert from `[]int8` to string?

For `[]byte` we could do `string(byteslice)`, but for `[]int8` it gives an error:

```
cannot convert ba (type []int8) to type string
```

I got the `ba` from `SliceScan()` method of [`*sqlx.Rows`](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx) that produces `[]int8` instead of `string`

Is this solution the fastest?

```
func B2S(bs []int8) string {
    ba := []byte{}
    for _, b := range bs {
        ba = append(ba, byte(b))
    }
    return string(ba)
}
```

**EDIT** my bad, it's `uint8` instead of `int8`.. so I can do `string(ba)` directly.

Comment: `string(u)` or `fmt.Sprintf("%s", u)` to set `[]uint8` to a sting. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62725637/12817546. `[]uint8("abc")` to set a string to `[]uint8`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62740786/12817546.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Note beforehand:** The asker first stated that input slice is `[]int8` so that is what the answer is for. Later he realized the input is `[]uint8` which can be directly converted to `string` because `byte` is an alias for `uint8` (and `[]byte` => `string` conversion is supported by the [language spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)).

---

You can't convert slices of different types, you have to do it manually.

Question is what type of slice should we convert to? We have 2 candidates: `[]byte` and `[]rune`. Strings are stored as UTF-8 encoded byte sequences internally (`[]byte`), and a `string` can also be converted to a slice of runes. The language supports converting both of these types (`[]byte` and `[]rune`) to `string`.

A `rune` is a unicode codepoint. And if we try to convert an `int8` to a `rune` in a one-to-one fashion, it will fail (meaning wrong output) if the input contains characters which are encoded to multiple bytes (using UTF-8) because in this case multiple `int8` values should end up in one `rune`.

Let's start from the string `"世界"` whose bytes are:

```
fmt.Println([]byte("世界"))
// Output: [228 184 150 231 149 140]
```

And its runes:

```
fmt.Println([]rune("世界"))
// [19990 30028]
```

It's only 2 runes and 6 bytes. So obviously 1-to-1 `int8`->`rune` mapping won't work, we have to go with 1-1 `int8`->`byte` mapping.

<sup>`byte` is alias for `uint8` having range `0..255`, to convert it to `[]int8` (having range `-128..127`) we have to use `-256+bytevalue` if the byte value is > 127 so the `"世界"` `string` in `[]int8` looks like this:</sup>

```
[-28 -72 -106 -25 -107 -116]
```

<sup>The backward conversion what we want is: `bytevalue = 256 + int8value` if the `int8` is negative but we can't do this as `int8` (range -128..127) and neither as `byte` (range 0..255) so we also have to convert it to `int` first (and back to `byte` at the end). This could look something like this:</sup>

```
if v < 0 {
    b[i] = byte(256 + int(v))
} else {
    b[i] = byte(v)
}
```

**But actually since signed integers are represented using [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), we get the same result if we simply use a `byte(v)` conversion (which in case of negative numbers this is equivalent to `256 + v`).**

**Note:** Since we know the length of the slice, it is much faster to allocate a slice with this length and just set its elements using indexing `[]` and not calling the built-in `append` function.

So here is the final conversion:

```
func B2S(bs []int8) string {
    b := make([]byte, len(bs))
    for i, v := range bs {
        b[i] = byte(v)
    }
    return string(b)
}
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/pCymfKl_Hp).

Answer (score 3):

Not entirely sure it is the fastest, but I haven't found anything better.
Change `ba := []byte{}` for `ba := make([]byte,0, len(bs)` so at the end you have:

```
func B2S(bs []int8) string {
    ba := make([]byte,0, len(bs))
    for _, b := range bs {
        ba = append(ba, byte(b))
    }
    return string(ba)
}
```

This way the append function will never try to insert more data that it can fit in the slice's underlying array and you will avoid unnecessary copying to a bigger array.

Answer (score 1):

What is sure from "[Convert between slices of different types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11924196/6309)" is that you have to build the right slice from your original `int8[]`.

I ended up using `rune` (`int32` alias) ([playground](http://play.golang.org/p/r6OZa5N2bC)), assuming that the uint8 were all simple ascii character. That is obviously an over-simplification and [icza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1705598/icza)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28848879/6309) has more on that.
Plus the [SliceScan()](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx/blob/69738bd209812c5a381786011aff17944a384554/sqlx.go#L674-L677) method ended up returning `uint8[]` anyway.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    s := []int8{'a', 'b', 'c'}
    b := make([]rune, len(s))
    for i, v := range s {
        b[i] = rune(v)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(b))
}
```

But I didn't benchmark it against using a `[]byte`.

Answer (score 0):

Use unsafe package.

```
func B2S(bs []int8) string {
  return strings.TrimRight(string(*(*[]byte)unsafe.Pointer(&bs)), "\x00")
}
```

Send again ^^

Comment: Please delete one of your answers as they are identical.

Comment: This is my first answer in stackoverflow.thks