# Putting int8 into byte array

Tags: go

I have the following byte array:

```
buf := make([]byte, 1)
var value int8
value = 45
buf[0] = value // cannot use type int8 as type []byte in assignment
```

And when I want to put a char value into the byte array I get the error that I `cannot use type int8 as type []byte in assignment`. What's wrong? How do I do this?

Comment: dont know much about `go` but have you either accidently made a array of an array? Or try casting int8 to byte first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert an integer to a byte array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16888357/convert-an-integer-to-a-byte-array)

Answer (score 3):

The issue you're having their is that although `int8` and `byte` are roughly equivalent, they're not the same type. Go is a little stricter about this than, say, PHP (which isn't strict about much). You can get around this by explicitly casting the value to `byte`:

```
buf := make([]byte, 1)
var value int8
value = 45
buf[0] = byte(value) // cast int8 to byte
```

Comment: Worth noting that `byte` is just an alias for `uint8` in Go.  That means the major difference is that you're trying to store a signed value into an unsigned slot.  Typecasting to `uint8`, or using a uint8 in the first place, works for this without needing a `byte` typecast.  Example: https://play.golang.org/p/XzQ7eWOS16

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
buf := make([]byte, 1)
var value int8
value = 45
buf[0] = byte(value)
```

**UPDATE**: Took out the code converting negative numbers to positive ones. It appears that `byte(...)` already does this conversion in current versions of Go.

Comment: No need this "tricky" conversion, a simple `byte(value)` gives the same result.

Comment: It looks like you're right! I wonder if something changed here... I had found an older resource that expressed the need to convert to a positive number first.

Comment: There was no change. Either the old source was incorrect, or maybe it related to another language? Or maybe that included constant expressions...

Comment: @icza Amazingly, I think my source was you! :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28848187/golang-convert-int8-to-string/28848879#28848879