# How to convert uint8 slice to string

Tags: go, type-conversion

What's the best way to convert from `[]uint8` to `string`?

I'm using http://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka

To read events from kafka. But it does not return plain string event.
It returns event with type `[]uint8`.
How can I convert this event from `[]uint8` to `string`?

Comment: Look here: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19223277/how-to-convert-uint8-to-string/21520223)

Comment: https://tour.golang.org/basics/13

Comment: Simply `string(uint8slice)`. See [How to convert \[\]int8 to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28848187/how-to-convert-int8-to-string/28848879?r=SearchResults#28848879).

Comment: Note that's a slice, not an array.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`byte` is an alias for `uint8`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types), which means that a slice of `uint8`) (aka `[]uint8`) is also a slice of `byte` (aka `[]byte`).

And byte slices and strings are directly convertible, due to the fact that strings are backed by byte slices:

```
myByteSlice := []byte{ ... }     // same as myByteSlice := []uint8{ ... }
myString := string(myByteSlice)  // myString is a string representation of the byte slice
myOtherSlice := []byte(myString) // Converted back to byte slice
```