# Is it possible to type cast from an int32 to an in64 and vice versa in Go?

Tags: go

I am trying to type cast between a slice of []int32 to a slice of []int64 in Go. Is there anyway i can convert between these types if not directly?

Comment: You can convert an int32 to int64 and back, but not the slices of those types. Create a new slice of needed type and convert elements one by one.

Comment: The answer to your title question is yes. The answer to your body question is no. Which is your actual question?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924196/convert-between-slices-of-different-types

Comment: And also: https://tour.golang.org/basics/13

Answer (score -2):

No it is not possible. The reason is that cells of the arrays backing those slices are made of either 4 or 8 bytes. Looking at 4 bytes as if it were 8 makes no sense. You need to copy the contents one by one.

Comment: That's why you can't assert one to the other, but has nothing to do with why you can't convert one to the other (otherwise the same would be true of int32 <-> int64, which you can convert between, and which also have different widths).